# iOS app - Logic to implement for in-app purchases

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

We have a non consumable IAP in our app which costs €3.49. I have purchased the IAP on my phone ages ago and also tested restore a couple of times and everything works just fine. This morning however, while testing the app, I uninstalled and installed the app from the App Store back on my phone. Instead of tapping 'Restore Purchases', I chose to 'Remove Ads', hence purchase the IAP again. I thought that the SDK(Xamarin.InAppPurchase) itself, would automatically track that I had previously purchased this IAP and it would go through the restore process on its own. However, I was proved wrong since a couple of minutes later, I received an invoice from Apple, that I had purchased the IAP again. I also received a statement from my bank for my purchase.

So my question here is: shouldn't the SDK itself check that the IAP was previously purchased under the Apple ID I was using? Should I amend my code on 'Remove Ads' to firstly go through the restore process and if I get a fail callback then move on to the actual purchase process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server side should check if non consumable purchase was made before or not.
In case if you try to buy second time your should get message like this:

> "You have already purchased this. Do you want to
>   purchase this again for free?"

It works for non consumable purchases. Check inside **itunesconnect** if your app really non consumable, probably you made it consumable by mistake.

Also FYI info from apple communities:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5574903

Comment: Thanks for the reply @yaroslavpalamar. This is what we thought as well. That server side should check if a non consumable purchase was made before or not and act accordingly. But it was not the case for me. The purchase went through again with no message whatsoever. I also checked on iTunesConnect and the purchase is non consumable, as expected.

Comment: Looks like need to write question to the apple support in this case.

Comment: Yes I guess so. So weird... Thanks again @yaroslavpalamar